# Accessing the __all__ list of the parent module of a class instance

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, module, namespaces

I have an instance of a class `SomeClass` that is defined within a module `m`. For the behavior of `SomeClass`, I need to access the following list:

```
m.__all__
```

How can I access this list from an instance of `SomeClass`?

Instances of `SomeClass` have the following built-in:

```
SomeClass.__module__
```

However, this is simply a string. How can I access the module itself, and its attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sys` module contains a dictionary [`modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) which maps the names of loaded modules to the modules themselves. Together with `SomeClass.__module__`, you can use this to access the module `SomeClass` was imported from.

For instance, with a module `m.py` like this:

```
# m.py

__all__ = [
    "A_CONSTANT",
    "SomeClass",
]

A_CONSTANT = "foo"

class SomeClass: pass
```

... the following works:

```
>>> from m import SomeClass
>>> SomeClass.__module__
'm'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules[SomeClass.__module__]
<module 'm' from '/path/to/m.py'>
>>> sys.modules[SomeClass.__module__].__all__
['SomeClass', 'A_CONSTANT']
>>> sys.modules[SomeClass.__module__].A_CONSTANT
'foo'
```